# Webservice in IBM Designer - Connection refused

Tags: web-services, wsdl, lotus-domino

I was trying to implement an Web Service Consumer from a different tool in our company. So the admin of this tool gave me a WSDL-File to import into our IBM Notes database (Sadly I'm not allowed to post the WSDL file here).

Now, when I want to create the new Web Service

[image]

by clicking ok I get the following error message "The requested operation failed: Connection refused: connect":

[image]

So I checked if our firewall blocked this request from our Domino server to the Tool server, but there was no request at all. The firewall showed nothing, so it seemed, this request never got out from the Domino server.

Did anybody get a similar error or can tell me, where I can check why Domino seems to block this request?
We have other Webservices running, so it can't be a general issue.

**Edit1:** Imports done in the WSDL file

```
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://Interflex.de/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.102.242:6042/InterflexServices/IF6040Service?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://Interflex.de" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.102.242:6042/InterflexServices/IF6040Service?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.102.242:6042/InterflexServices/IF6040Service?xsd=xsd2" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Interflex.IF6040.ServiceLayer.PublishedServices" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.102.242:6042/InterflexServices/IF6040Service?xsd=xsd3" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.102.242:6042/InterflexServices/IF6040Service?xsd=xsd4" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Interflex.IF6040.ServiceLayer.PublishedServices.SharedDataContracts" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="http://192.168.102.242:6042/InterflexServices/IF6040Service?xsd=xsd5" namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/Interflex.IF6040.Modules.Recording.PersonEvents.Global.EventProcessing" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
```

Comment: Does the wsdl include any imports from URIs or any other references to URIs?

Comment: I've appended the imports done in the WSDL file

Comment: A 192.168 address is in a private address space. A "connection refused" messaqe could indicate that the machine that is running Domino Designer is being blocked from connecting to port 6042 on the server at that IPaddress. What happens if you open a browser on that same machine and enter one of those URLs?

Comment: In the browser those URLs open without any error. I can see some XML Code. So it seems, that the connection in general works.